# create a trigger on a new table which is generated from select considering three tables

Tags: mysql, indexing, triggers

this is my country table

```
create table country(id int auto_increment primary key, 
country_name varchar(100),
country_code varchar(10), 
provider_country_id varchar(50), 
provider_id int);
```

this is my state table

```
create table state(id int primary key auto_increment, 
state_name varchar(100), 
provider_state_id varchar(50), 
provider_id int, 
country_id int, 
foreign key(country_id) references country(id) on delete set null);
```

this is my city table

```
create table city(id int primary key auto_increment, 
city_name varchar(100), 
provider_city_id varchar(50), 
state_id int, 
foreign key(state_id) references state(id) on delete set null, 
country_id int, 
foreign key(country_id) references country(id) on delete set null, 
provider_id int);
```

i have created a new table as

```
create table new_table 
select city.id as cityId, city.provider_city_id as providerCityId, city.city_name as cityName, state.state_name as stateName, country.country_name as countryName, country.country_code as countryCode, state.id as stateId, city.state_id as stateIdFromCity, country.id as countryId, state.country_id as countryIdFromState from city city,state state, country country 
where city.state_id = state.id and state.country_id = country.id;
```

then i have also created an index as

```
create index multi_idx on new_table(stateId, stateIdFromCity, countryId, countryIdFromState);
```

now i have to create a trigger on new_table on insert, delete,update on those three tables. how to do that?

Comment: Does you want to insert (update, delete) the data into old 3 tables when the data is inserted (updated, deleted) in new table? I.e. you'll work with new table only, and the data in old 3 tables must alter accordingly?

Comment: A trigger will fire only from the table which it is defined on - You cannot create a trigger on new_table which will recognise that an insert has occurred on country(for example) if you want to cause an action on event on an insert to country then the trigger has to be on country. In your case it looks like you need 9 triggers , an insert,update,delete for each table.

Answer (score 0):

"Over-normalization".

Just have a single table with one row per city.  In it have country, state/province, city.  Call the table `Locations` or `Cities`.

Meanwhile, `country_code` should be `CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii` and use the international 2-letter standard.

Or, in some related situations, base it on postal_code.